# Packets not getting forwarded on Centos7 between GRE tunnels

Tags: linux, networking, tunnel

I'm have configured GRE tunnels between centos machines and corresponding routing tables on individual centos machines as shown in the image:

[image]
Im able to
Ping from Router-1 to gre1 tunnels other end:

```
worker]# ping 10.0.0.2
PING 10.0.0.2 (10.0.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.43 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.472 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.291 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.319 ms
```

The traffic reaches Transit Router over the GRE tunnel(this is verified by tcpdump proto gre)

Ping from Router-2 to gre2 tunnels other end:

```
worker]# ping 11.0.0.2
PING 11.0.0.2 (11.0.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 11.0.0.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.10 ms
64 bytes from 11.0.0.2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.392 ms
64 bytes from 11.0.0.2: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.369 ms
64 bytes from 11.0.0.2: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.258 ms
```

This traffic too flows on tunnel

and on the transit router I'm able to ping the private address of both Router-1 and Router-2 after adding the routing entry:
Transit Router:

```
[root@vmc-centos conf]# ping 10.2.32.1
PING 10.2.32.1 (10.2.32.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.2.32.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.589 ms
64 bytes from 10.2.32.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.380 ms
64 bytes from 10.2.32.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.383 ms
```

Router-1:

```
worker]# tcpdump -i any proto gre -n
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 65535 bytes
04:54:36.684864 IP 10.206.83.3 > 10.206.90.103: GREv0, length 88: IP 10.0.0.2 > 10.2.32.1: ICMP echo request, id 20445, seq 34, length 64
04:54:36.684951 IP 10.206.90.103 > 10.206.83.3: GREv0, length 88: IP 10.2.32.1 > 10.0.0.2: ICMP echo reply, id 20445, seq 34, length 64
04:54:37.684776 IP 10.206.83.3 > 10.206.90.103: GREv0, length 88: IP 10.0.0.2 > 10.2.32.1: ICMP echo request, id 20445, seq 35, length 64
```

Transit Router:

```
[root@vmc-centos conf]# ping 10.4.32.1
PING 10.4.32.1 (10.4.32.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.4.32.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.553 ms
64 bytes from 10.4.32.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.325 ms
64 bytes from 10.4.32.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.354 ms
```

Router-2:

```
worker]# sudo tcpdump -i any proto gre -n
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 65535 bytes
04:56:57.549823 IP 10.206.83.3 > 10.206.86.199: GREv0, length 88: IP 11.0.0.2 > 10.4.32.1: ICMP echo request, id 20690, seq 24, length 64
04:56:57.549896 IP 10.206.86.199 > 10.206.83.3: GREv0, length 88: IP 10.4.32.1 > 11.0.0.2: ICMP echo reply, id 20690, seq 24, length 64
```

But now when I try to reach the private network of Router-2(10.4.32.1) from Router-1, the packets reach till Transit Router but are not being forwarded from there to Router-2:
Router-1:

```
worker]# ping 10.4.32.1
PING 10.4.32.1 (10.4.32.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

Transit Router:

```
[root@vmc-centos conf]# tcpdump -i any proto gre -n
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 262144 bytes
04:59:06.382024 IP 10.206.90.103 > 10.206.83.3: GREv0, length 88: IP 10.0.0.1 > 10.4.32.1: ICMP echo request, id 36131, seq 40, length 64
04:59:07.382007 IP 10.206.90.103 > 10.206.83.3: GREv0, length 88: IP 10.0.0.1 > 10.4.32.1: ICMP echo request, id 36131, seq 41, length 64
```

Router-2:

```
[root@wdc-10-206-86-199 worker]# sudo tcpdump -i any proto gre -n
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 65535 bytes
```

Route forwarding is enabled on all the machines:

```
[root@vmc-centos conf]# sudo sysctl -p
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

iptables on transit router:

```
[root@vmc-centos ~]# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     gre  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     gre  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     gre  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Note: I have tried this before and the packets were reaching the other private network. Now Im trying on another setup, theres some config I'm missing.

Comment: Just curious why is it being downvoted? Just so that I'll correct the mistake in future?

Comment: This doesn't look like a *programming* question, so it is **off-topic** on Stack Overflow. The answer you have got on [sf] is just a confirmation of off-topic.

Comment: Sure will keep this in mind thank you @Tsyvarev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the answer here:
https://serverfault.com/questions/1010565/packets-not-getting-forwarded-on-centos7-between-gre-tunnels

The Docker daemon seems to be running on the forwarding machine. By default to isolate containers on different bridges and the host machine, Docker will install a default DROP policy on the forwarding chain in iptables. There is a setting in Docker daemon to not do this. Set iptables to false in /etc/docker/daemon.json. See Docker and iptables.

If you change default policy to ACCEPT, that will work.

```
iptables --policy FORWARD ACCEPT
```

BUT, when you (or a package upgrade of docker, or a reboot) restarts the Docker daemon the default policy will again change to DROP, if you didn't change the setting of the docker daemon.